# Will GitHub pull requests remain open for a user after revoking access?

Tags: git, github

A particular employee opened a number of pull requests in GitHub against a private repository.  The employee has since gone on to other opportunities, but their pull requests are still open (and still need to be reviewed/merged).

If I revoke that user's access to our private repository, will that user's pull requests still remain open, or will they be deleted?  It seems logical that they would remain open, as Git will still track a history of all commits by that user, but I'm not quite comfortable testing this, as I don't want to lose any open pull requests by that user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Removing organization members from a team](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-organization-members-from-a-team/):

> **Warning**: If you remove a person’s access to a private repository, any of their forks of that private repository are deleted. Local clones of the private repository are retained. If a team's access to a private repository is revoked or a team with access to a private repository is deleted, and team members do not have access to the repository through another team, private forks of the repository will be deleted.

Thus, if the pull requests are from a private fork to the main private repo, the commits will be deleted with the rest of their fork, which would cause the PR to be closed.

However, if they have pushed their branch to the main private repo and created a PR from that, I see no reason why that PR should be deleted.

Worst case, you could ensure that you have a copy of all the commits locally, then remove the user. If any PRs are closed, push the relevant branches and open new ones.

Comment: In our case, they didn't fork, but they did pull request and push it as a branch to the main private repo.  

Thanks!